# Limit of $\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> A continuous function $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a limit $\alpha = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> (1) Let  $ g(t) = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(x) dx$. Show $\lim_{t \to \infty} g(t) = \alpha$.
>
> (2) Let  $ h(t) = \frac{1}{t^2} \int_0^t xf(x) dx$. Show the existence of limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} g(t)$ and get the value.

I cannot answer to neither. My approach is using mean value theorem for definite integral. So there is the real nunber $c (t)\in [0,\infty)$  s.t. $f(c) = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(x) dx $. However I have no idea from here. Thank you.

---

Answer.

Since $f$ is continuous and take limit $\alpha$, for any $\epsilon$ there exsits $c \in \mathbb{R}$ succh that $|f(x)- \alpha| \leq \epsilon$ whenever $c \leq x$.

(1) We get $\int_c^t (\alpha - \epsilon) dx \leq \int_c^t f(x) dx \leq \int_c^t (\alpha + \epsilon) dx$. Add $\int_0^c f(x) dx$ and divide by t and take $t \to \infty$, we get something like $(\alpha - \epsilon) \leq \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f(x) dx \leq (\alpha + \epsilon)$.

(2) We get $\int_c^t x(\alpha - \epsilon) dx \leq \int_c^t xf(x) dx \leq \int_c^t x(\alpha + \epsilon) dx$. Add $\int_0^c xf(x) dx$ and divide by $t^2$ and take $t \to \infty$, we get something like $\frac{1}{2}(\alpha - \epsilon) \leq \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t^2}\int_0^t xf(x) dx \leq \frac{1}{2}(\alpha + \epsilon)$. This shows existence of limit and value is $\frac{1}{2}\alpha$ (this subtly follow from  l'Hôpital's theorem to $h(t)$).

Comment: Compare $f$ with the constant function $F(x) = \alpha$

Comment: Use LHospital Rule for both the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $(\alpha -\epsilon) (t-s) < \int_s^{t} f(x)dx \leq (t-s) (\alpha +\epsilon)$ if $s$ is sufficiently large. Divide by $t$ and take the limit. Note that $\frac  1 t \int_0^{s} f(x)dx \to 0$ as $ t \to \infty$. Proof of the second part is similar.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Because $f$ is continuous over $[0,\infty)$ with finite limit $\alpha$, $|f(x)|$ is bounded; that is, there exists an $M > 0$ for which $|f(x)|< M$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Because $f(x) \to \alpha$, there exists a $c \in \Bbb R$ such that $|f(x) - \alpha| < \epsilon$ whenever $x > c$.

With that, find upper and lower bounds for $g(t)$ in terms of $\epsilon$ assuming that $t > c$.

A similar approach can be applied for part 2.

---

Alternatively: show that both $\int_0^tf(x)\,dx$ and $\int_0^t xf(x)\,dx$ go to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$, then apply L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: the first sentence isn't true as stated, because continuity alone doesn't imply boundedness; we also need to use the fact that the limit at infinity is finite (of course you mention this later on, but it's perhaps worth rewording slightly to avoid potential confusion).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Good catch, I agree, see my latest edit.